# Optimizing string handling function

Tags: performance, c, strings

How can I optimize the following function? It checks whether two strings have a certain number of similar consecutive characters. As it is now, it is very slow, so how can it be improved in terms of speed/performance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int overlap(char *str, const char *substr, int length);

int main(void)
{
    if (overlap("abcef01239", "abckef01798", 4))
    {
        puts("Match ...");
    }
    return 0;
}

int overlap(char *str, const char *substr, int length)
{
    const char *_sub = substr;
    while (*str)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int a = *str;
        int b = *substr;
        while (a && b)
        {
            if (a != b)
                break;

            n++;
            if (n == length)
                return 1;

            a = str[n];
            b = substr[n];
        }
        if (!*substr)
        {
            str++;
            substr = _sub;
        }
        else
        {
            substr++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't know why you find it incomplete. It describes what the code does: "_It checks whether two strings have a certain number of similar consecutive characters_" and explains the problem that it is _slow_.

Comment: After several re-reads, I *think* the intent is that it should return true if the two strings have any common substring of `length` or more characters.  Is that the case?  If so, you could make it clearer by including more of your tests.

Comment: @TobySpeight The function is supposed to return true if there are equivalent _consecutive_ characters of length `length` between two strings. In `main()`, it returns true because "abc**ef01**239" and "abck**ef01**798 have exactly `4` similar consecutive characters, which is the length passed as the third argument.

Answer (score 2):

## Const correctness

We don't modify the contents of `str`, so pass it as a `const char*`.  This allows us to give string literals as arguments without compiler warnings.

## Check the arguments

What if `str` or `substr` is null?  What does it mean for `length` to be negative?  We should use `size_t` for indexing and lengths.

```
int overlap(const char *str, const char *substr, size_t length)
{
    if (!str || !substr)
        /* invalid arguments */
        return 0;
```

## Add more tests

I'm not 100% sure from the description what the code is supposed to do.  That can be made clearer by providing more tests.  I recommend using a test framework to help identify the failures, but we can make our own for this:

```
int test(const char *a, const char *b, size_t len,
         int expected, const char *file, int line, const char *message)
{
    const int actual = overlap(a, b, len);
    if (actual == expected) return 0;

    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: %s should be %d, but got %d\n",
            file, line,
            message, expected, actual);
    return 1;
}

#define TEST(a, b, len, expected) \
    test(a, b, len, expected, __FILE__, __LINE__, "overlap(" #a ", " #b  ", " #len ")")

int main(void)
{
    return
        + TEST(NULL, NULL, 1, 0)
        + TEST("abc", "def", 0, 1)
        + TEST("abc", "abc", 4, 0)
        + TEST("abc", "abc", 3, 1)
        + TEST("abc", "bcd", 3, 0)
        + TEST("abc", "bcd", 2, 1)
        + TEST("bcd", "abc", 2, 1)
        + TEST("abcef01239", "abckef01798", 4, 1);
}
```

## Algorithm

We're going more times over the data than we need to - although it looks like we're scaling as *O(n²)*, it's actually *O(n³)*, because of the `if`/`else` at the end of the loop that resets `substr` from time to time.

What we need to do is for each offset of `str` and `substr`, walk along the pair of them, counting character matches as we go (reset the count on a non-match).  If the count reaches `length`, then we've found a substring match.

As a worked example, let's test `"ab1cdefg"` against `"bcde2"`:

```
ab1cdefg
bcde2
.....
```

In that first pass, nothing matched.  Now shift one of the strings by one character (i.e. index by `n+1` instead of by `n`):

```
ab1cdefg
 bcde2
 1....
```

The longest run was 1, when we matched the `b`.  Next iteration:

```
ab1cdefg
  bcde2
  .123.
```

Here, we matched `c`, `d` and `e` successively, for a run length of 3.

In code, that looks something like:

```
#include <string.h>

/* internal method - returns true if a and b are equal for a run of
   length, without shifting */
static int overlap_run(const char *a, const char *b, size_t length)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*a && *b) {
        /* add one to count, or reset it to 0 */
        if (*a == *b)
            ++count;
        else
            count = 0;

        if (count == length)
            /* match found */
            return 1;

        ++a, ++b;
    }
    return 0;
}

int overlap(const char *a, const char *b, size_t length)
{
    if (!a || !b)
        /* invalid arguments */
        return 0;

    if (!length)
        /* every pair of strings has a zero-length match */
        return 1;

    const size_t la = strlen(a);
    const size_t lb = strlen(b);

    if (length > la || length > lb)
        /* strings are too short to match */
        return 0;

    for (size_t offset = 0;  offset <= la - length;  ++offset)
        if (overlap_run(a+offset, b, length))
            return 1;

    for (size_t offset = 1;  offset <= lb - length;  ++offset)
        if (overlap_run(a, b+offset, length))
            return 1;

    /* no match */
    return 0;
}
```

You might be able to avoid pipeline stalls by replacing

```
    if (*a == *b)
        ++count;
    else
        count = 0;
```

With

```
    count += (*a == *b);
    count *= (*a == *b);
```

But you'll need to benchmark to find out on your hardware.

Comment: Well, `assert()` is generally the proper way to check for programmer error, instead of returning an error-code.

Comment: Unfortunately the spec doesn't say whether passing NULL is an error or not, so I'm sitting on the fence there!

Comment: @TobySpeight Most standard library C functions do not  specify functionality when a string pointer is `NULL`, thus it is UB when those functions are called with  `NULL`.   Of course employing code that does have a `NULL` test is OK - and reasonably of low cost.